# Scala type mis-match: Nothing => Nothing?

Tags: scala

First stackoverflow question and new to Scala. Trying to understand polymorphic types with this example I wrote:

```
def identFun[A](a: A): A = a

def testerChar(l: List[Char], f: Char => Char): List[Char] = {
  val li = l.map((r: Char) => f(r: Char))
  li
}
```

Which works fine (if not a bit verbose):

```
scala> testerChar(List('a','b','c'), identFun)
res49: List[Char] = List(a, b, c)
```

However:

```
def testerA[A](l: List[A], f: A => A): List[A] = {
  val li = l.map((r: A) => f(r: A))
  li
}
```

Yields:

```
scala> testerA(List('a','b','c'), identFun)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Nothing => Nothing
 required: Char => Char
       testerA(List('a','b','c'), identFun)
```

What am I missing that would allow "testerA" to return identities for any type passed to it?

Thanks!

Tried:

```
def testerA[A](l: List[A])( f: A => A): List[A] = {
  val li = l.map((r: A) => f(r: A))
  li
}
```

Got:

```
scala> testerA(List('a','b','c'), identFun)
<console>:14: error: too many arguments for method testerA: (l: List[A])(f: A => A)List[A]
   testerA(List('a','b','c'), identFun)
```

Comment: change it to `def testerA[A](l: List[A])( f: A => A)`

Comment: Or deliver the type. testerA[Char](List('a','b','c'), identFun)

Comment: The curried `def` should be called like this: `testerA(List(...))(identFun)`, using `)(` in place of the `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can also get what you're after if you simplify things.

```
scala> def identFun[A](a: A): A = a
identFun: [A](a: A)A

scala> def testerA[A](l: List[A])(f: A => A): List[A] = l.map(f)
testerA: [A](l: List[A])(f: A => A)List[A]

scala> testerA(List('a','b','c'))(identFun)
res5: List[Char] = List(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain how to fix the problem, but not the problem itself. The issue is that when you write `testerA(List('a','b','c'), identFun)` without specifying the type argument, Scala can't use the first argument to infer `A` and then use `A` to figure out the type of the second argument.

Instead it typechecks both arguments first. Again, it needs to infer type arguments for both `List.apply` and for `identFun`. In the first case, it chooses `Char` (of course), but in the second it chooses `Nothing`. After this it tries to finally decide on `A`, but of course the arguments aren't compatible now.

With `def testerA[A](l: List[A])(f: A => A)`, `A` is inferred using the first argument and then used to typecheck `f`.

Comment: Thank you @AlexeyRomanov for your explanation. I had come to the same conclusion from my Haskell experience. Thank you to all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For me, calling it like this worked:

```
testerA(List('a','b','c'), identFun[Char])
```

I suspect that type A of testerA is a different type than identFun's type A. I'm not sure how you would cause it to automatically resolve to char.

Comment: Update, this also works: testerA[Char](List('a', 'b', 'c'), identFun)